# Find PHP process that logs to file

Tags: apache-2.2, php, bash, process

I have started a PHP script via browser and due to a loop error the script continues to be executed even after closing the browser. I am noticing it since the script is logging error messages to my logfile (path known).

We have a Apache server where many developers work together and the user is `nmdev`. So how can I find out what process it the one running and logging to my logfile?

`ps -afe | grep php53` gives me many processes of today like:

`nmdev 26518 24151 0 11:51 ? 00:00:00 /opt/xxx/yyy/apache-php5/bin/httpd -k start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem was to use:

`/sbin/fuser /path/to/logfile`

That gave me all the processes writing to the file. I killed them all without mercy. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

The tool [lsof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) with the complete path of your file will give you a list of all processes which are accessing to it.

Example:

```
me@home ~ % lsof /home/me                                    
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
i3bar      1894 me  cwd    DIR    8,3    32768 4718593 /home/me
j4status   1895 me  cwd    DIR    8,3    32768 4718593 /home/me
germinal   1899 me  cwd    DIR    8,3    32768 4718593 /home/me
```

Comment: Yes I know `lsof` but it is not available `-bash: lsof: command not found` and I am not root.

Comment: Perhaps you should install it in this case...

Comment: Ok, just saw you're NOT root. You'll have to be root (or at least be allowed to use sudo) in order to use lsof...